# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find installable ISAM.' - MS Access (.accdb) and C# (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

There were few similar questions here, but i couldn't locate any with acceptable answer. or that it would actually work one.

I have create a local storage as .accdb file and tried to connect witch c# to it.

In summary those are the parts needed:

```
public static string accessConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\MS_Access_Test_DB.accdb";

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

It always crashes, with an error from description. I had tried to use apostrophes, quotes etc for `C:\MS_Access_Test_DB.accdb`

I had also tried `JET.4.0` with same error & adding `Persist Security Info=True;` into the mix.

Comment: There are a *lot* of similar questions, and the answers are clear. You need to install the correct driver and specify the correct version in the connection string. `Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0` is ancient. The current driver is ACE and you need to install the correct version *and* specify that in the connection string. This has nothing to do with paths and quotes, or persisting passwords

Comment: Hello. yes there are ton of similar questions and non of the answers are actually works or adresses the issue in clear way. like i had mentioned i had tried using ACE.OLEDB.12.0, still with same error, the drivers arent the issue as with ACE.OLEDB.12.0 i was able to connect to Excel file and extract table and i had tested it right now.

Comment: The driver and application bitness must match too. You can't load a 32-bit driver in a 64-bit application and vice-versa. You'll have to install the driver that matches the bitness of your application. If you target `Any CPU` you'll have to switch to a specific target and install the correct driver

Comment: `none of the answers are actually works` they work. MS Access isn't a new product, and neither is .NET. By now it's 20 years old. The problem you have was encountered and solved by thousands of developers in the past. You need to install the correct driver. The [latest Access Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) is `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable`. You also need to match targets - 32 or 64 bit. ACE is a native driver and can only be loaded in a matching application

Comment: On 32 bit i get an error i had described in title, while error i get while compiling at 64 bit i get: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Comment: Additionaly, like i had mentioned i added a void to test excel connection on same provider, it works fine.
`OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
  openFile.ShowDialog();
  string excelFilePath = openFile.FileName;
  OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
            excelConnection.Open(); `

Comment: Jet OleDb 4.0 cannot read accdb files. You should use (as @PanagiotisKanavos has already told you at least three times) the new drivers with the bitness compatible with your app

Comment: Installing them now, ill get back if this will work, i still don't get why the excel connection works then and access does not?

Comment: Post your actual code, connection string, driver version and target runtime. `I get an error` doesn't answer any of these. Especially when the wrong provider string is used in the question. `provider is not registered on the local machine` that says you haven't installed the 64-bit driver. It doesn't say which version was installed though. 2010? 2016? Something in between?

Comment: `and access does not?` the Access format has changed over the years. You may have a database created by a newer version, even though the extension is the same. Frankly, few people use Access. It's a bad option for web applications, SQLite is better (and free-er) as an embedded option and for multiple clients, SQL Server Express is *infinitely* better. The bitness issue is a serious problem too. It's not just what you have installed on your machine, but what your *users* have.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot use normal SQL (0,- budget), SQLite requires external drivers to connect to PowerBI (again, 0,- budget)). I'm stuck with access i remember that a while back it worked fine, now I'm in the world of pain...

Comment: SQL Server Express is free

Comment: Yes, but you still need a PC that is running as "server". Unfortunately i need something accessible all day long from a shared drive. 

On the other note i  move the solution to my home enviroment, had same issue: tried to install driver for x64, got an error that i cannot install driver as i have installed 32 bit Office. Then i tried to install 32 bit driver and got error that i cannot install it, as i have 64 bit office. Nothing was reinstalled..... 

Still don't understand why would excel connection work while access isn't... :(

Comment: 64 bit office. Nothing was reinstalled..... 

On that note, isn't the issue related to 64bit windows and 32bit office, rather than build selected?

Comment: How did you create your MS_Access_Test_DB.accdb file?

Comment: right click -> new -> access db :)

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz ok, i've seen already 0 byte 'database' files ;)

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz like create new .txt and rename it in .accdb/mdb. Or simple File.Create without any content. Also, somebody saved a word document as .mdb... Some of these files  also lead to your error.

Comment: Ok :D No, im not that dumb.
I had created a table, wrote class for it and did set dapper to insert data, but im stuck at connection. Considering it may work for me, and not other users im mostly thinking about either SQL SE on VM (not sure if that's possible) or SQLite and dropping the PowerBi... I can build statistics with LiveCharts nugets.

Comment: Ok, im dumber than i thought issue was: was `DataSource` insted of `Data Source` , and although im building on 64bit and office is in 32bit it seems to work.

Comment: To add to above, connections are established i had created a  tool to test speed read/writes between Access DB and SQLite. It seems that shared drive is massive bottleneck, that SQLite is approx 3 times slower than Access DB

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

The issue as pointed out by Steeeve & Panagiotis Kanavos using is access driver 32bit when i use 64bit architecture, and this will not work. Especially in office/corporation that already has a lot of build in add-ins for office 32 bit. There is also workaround, to install both drivers, but it would require each user to have it, therefore it wasn't solution in my case.

Id much prefer using SQLite, but the tables have to be connected to PowerBI i now that SQLite have to use external drivers to update datasets, therefore for now, this solution was also out.

Considering I cannot force each user to change drivers etc. I tried and saved the access file as .mdb (2002-2003).

So it's either: intalling 64bit driver (proposed initialy) or a workaround (with .mdb):

```
public static string accessConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MS_Access_Test_DB.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

Or:

```
public static string accessConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MS_Access_Test_DB.mdb";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
            connection.Open();
```

Important note, there is lot of .accdb functionalities that cannot be used in .mdb, so if you have to use access, than be carefull. If you can, consider SQLite/SQL SE proposed in comment's under my question.

EDIT: I had also messed up the first time... Instead of `DataSource` I should have had `Data Source` so it seems to work, despite using Driver 32bit against 64bit app.